# Find the Panda and the Cat - Dudolf puzzle

Tags: image-processing

I recently find [this puzzle](https://www.facebook.com/thedudolf/photos/a.479677258800858.1073741834.380909998677585/718818741553374/?type=3&theater) where you have to find the panda from a group of snowmen. Having a horrible eyesight I have to take help of mathematica to find it.

I start with assumption that all snowmen have orange nose (carrots), so find them out and eliminate them.

```
img = Import[
    "http://i1.tribune.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/947083_718818741553374_3000781901216554446_n.jpg"];
img = ImageResize[img, 500];

pts = ImageValuePositions[img, Orange, .2];
img1 = Show[img, Epilog -> {Gray, Disk[#, 12] & /@ pts}]

Grid[{Show[#, ImageSize -> {400, 400}] & /@ {img, img1}}]
```

[image]

It is now a bit easier to spot the panda. But the method will fail if the panda has any orange patch in its face.

Is it possible to define facial pattern (in this case black eyes with long orange nose, that is number of orange pixel higher than a threshold) along with the colour to spot the snowmen?

> **A closely related post**

As pointed out by march, this post ([How do I find Waldo with Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica)) is close to what I am trying to do. The difference is Here I know the pattern to eliminate (the carrot nose) and all the noses does not follow the same structure. So I don't think a single `ImageCorrelate` can find all the noses.

> Find the cat

I found another puzzle by the same author where you have to [find the cat from a group of owls](https://www.facebook.com/thedudolf/photos/a.479677258800858.1073741834.380909998677585/720342174734364/?type=3).

Again, I pick the (yellow) beak, and it make the job much easier.

```
img = Import["http://laughingsquid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Find-the-Cat.png?w=750"];
img = ImageResize[img, 500];
pts = ImageValuePositions[img, Yellow, .2];
img1 = Show[img, Epilog -> {Brown, Disk[#, 30] & /@ pts}];

Grid[{Show[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {img, img1}}]
```

[image]

It works well for this image, but sometimes it fails for other images (by other images I mean same image from different sources suggested by google search) where the colours are not very prominent. One owl actually survived here also (top right corner). So I am still looking for a way to combine a small range of colour with a pattern to spot the 'not'.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica)?

Comment: Thanks @march for pointing that. But you will still have the same problem. You see there are several structures of noses, so a single `ImageCorrelate` would not be able to capture them all.

Comment: Ummm, I have a question (raises hand). If the panda is spotted, doesn't that mean it's, like, maybe a leopard?

Comment: hmmm @DanielLichtblau, in that case we have to `ImageIdentify` to make sure it is a panda, not a leopard (or a bear in disguise) ;)

Comment: I think Danny's question is along the lines of "How could the tiger escape the zoo without being spotted?